# Avoiding looping when operations on repeated identifier

Tags: r, loops, identifier

Very often I struggle to do basic operations in R because I have to control for unique identifier.

I work most of the time with "long format" data.

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A1", 3), rep("B1", 3)),
             activity = c(15,17,12,3,4,15),
             begin = c( 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2 ) )
```

For example, computing time or observation by identifier

```
dt$time <- 1
for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
  if(dt[i,'id'] == dt[i-1, 'id'])
  {
    dt[i,'time'] <- dt[i-1,'time'] + 1
  }
}
```

or double checking repeated data

```
dt$zerocheck = 0 
for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
  if( dt[i,'id'] == dt[i-1, 'id'] & 
        dt[i,'begin'] == dt[i-1, 'begin'] )  
  {
   dt$zerocheck[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

I guess the answer will be something like aggregate by id, but I am not entirely sure.

```
merge(dt, aggregate(time ~ id, dt, "max"), by=c("id"), all.X=T)
```

Any suggestions in order to avoid doing loops ?

Comment: If the sequence your data appears in is important, you probably want to add a row-number variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add onto the other examples, you could also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time = row_number()) %>% # creates the control for identifier
  mutate(zerocheck= ifelse(begin==lag(begin), 1, 0)) # checks for repeated data
```

or equivalently you could just use a single mutate function like the following:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time = row_number(), 
         zerocheck=begin==lag(begin))
```

The first query has the output:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: id

  id activity begin time zerocheck
1 A1       15     0    1        NA
2 A1       17     0    2         1
3 A1       12     1    3         0
4 B1        3     0    1        NA
5 B1        4     1    2         0
6 B1       15     2    3         0
```

For the `zerocheck` case I simply used lag to check the previous value was the same as the current value. This mimics the code you have in your question. Of course if you want to check something else, you can quite easily alter the predicate.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a single `mutate`?

Comment: @Frank yes, the `ifelse` also not needed.

Comment: I agree, you could just remove the `ifelse`, I was probably trying too hard to copy the output precisely, you could do it in a single mutate, like: `mutate(time = row_number(), zerocheck=begin==lag(begin))`. I'll change the above.

Answer (score 4):

These operations can be simplified with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, `:=`(time = seq_len(.N), zerocheck = begin == shift(begin)), by = id]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! I still have to learn more about the data.table package. I am not familiar with it. So you think it is a waste of time to re-write these loops in Rccp for example ? I feel that I have more control over what I am doing with a loop. What do you think ?

Comment: @giacomoV It's possible Rcpp could speed it up, yeah, but that doesn't mean it's worth your time :) I think `zerocheck` shouldn't take much time to compute to begin with, but if you have time to spare or want to learn Rcpp, I'd say go for it.